# Can't unlist and retain top level names in 1st column

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to unlist all variables from a list of length 3.

The data shows:

```
df_list   list3 (These are each sheet with row/column data)
sheet 1   tbl_df
sheet 2   tbl_df
sheet 3   tbl_df
```

I am trying to use:

```
as.data.frame(table(unlist(df_list,use.names = T,recursive = T)),row.names = T)

data.table(unlist(df_list),keep.rownames = T)

data.table(all_vars = unlist(df_list,recursive = T,use.names = T),keep.rownames = TRUE)
```

I all three scenarios I get returned one output column of all variables from the list elements that are listed

```
col1
all
all
all
```

Where I am trying to get

```
col1     col2
sheet 1  all
sheet 1  all
sheet 2  all
sheet 2  all
sheet 2  all
sheet 3  all
sheet 3  all
```

Is this possible? Thank you. I'd like to do some data checking with dplyr once this is done and run some group by's, remove na's from col2, and do some duplicate checks etc. But I really need those sheet names so I can see where the data is housed between sets. Thank you.

The dput is from using `test <- data.table(all_vars = unlist(df_list),keep.rownames = T)`

```
structure(list(all_vars = c("searchs,top 10,austintexas.gov,website", 
"dog,dogs,pet,off-leash,areas,area", "cat,dog,pet,stray,austin animal center,no kill,data,open government,map", 
"dangerous,dogs,public safety,pets,animals", NA, "restaurant,geodata,health,fdhealth", 
"fire,afd,stations,fire stations", "unclaimed,property,unclaimed property", 
"water quality,eii,ali,barton springs,lady bird lake,lake austin,salamanders,barton creek,bull creek,bacteria,coli", 
"google,fiber,gigabit,tara,community,connections")), row.names = c(NA, 
-10L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x0000023dd1999f50>)
```

summary of list

```
                                Length Class  Mode
all_views_20161003               16    tbl_df list
city_departments_in_current_bud   6    tbl_df list
crosswalk_to_budget_dept          2    tbl_df list
site_metrics                    285    tbl_df list
site_metrics_20161102           263    tbl_df list
table_metrics_ytd                30    tbl_df list
```

Comment: Updated with dput top 10 returns

Comment: The dput shows a regular dataset column, it is not a tbl_df.  Also, where are the sheet names you mentioned

Comment: Can you show the `dput(df_list[1:5])` because by converting to `data.table`, you are losing the names

Comment: If I dput the list it's an insane amount of info. I provided a summary if that helps? Thanks you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the current option, we may  `unlist` the list elements and then `stack`

```
test <- stack(lapply(df_list, unlist))[2:1]
```

---

Or another option is

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
map_dfr(df_list, ~ tibble(col2 = unlist(.x)), .id = 'col1')
```

Comment: I have tried the bind rows option - keep in mind, I am trying to get a vertical or I guess long list of ALL variables stacked in a single column. I believe when I did that I got the entire data frame - while yes retaining sheet names. But I am not trying to get all data as a frame with sheet name retention

Comment: @DreDay try the update

Comment: The error I receive with 1st method `Error in as.data.table.list(x, keep.rownames = keep.rownames, check.names = check.names,  : 
  (converted from warning) Item 1 has 1972 rows but longest item has 54509; recycled with remainder.`

The update worked on `map_dfr` - Thanks! 

Comment: @DreDay can you try the update.  I was thinking that you had a single column per list earlier